# Truffle debug on function call show null variables

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, local-variables

With a `truffle` version of `4.1.0`, using `truffle debug` on a call of my contract function below:

```
function Deposit (uint256 timeout, bytes32 hash, address recipient)
        public payable returns (uint256)
    {
        require( timeout >= now );
        require( timeout < (now + MAX_TIMEOUT) );
        require( msg.value > 0 );

        var lock_id = m_ctr;
        m_ctr += 1;
        m_locks[lock_id] = LockState(timeout, hash, recipient, msg.sender, msg.value);

        OnDeposit(lock_id, recipient);

        return lock_id;
    }
```

as (via geth):

```
Deposit(1521568000, '0xffcec51439a3a7195c8f5c32732bfc2bf66688a13c1d52fc9d5e548f4733b5c1,', "0x0e0060f625534293d280547bd8a782da45333b95", {from: "0x4a7268f1982acd8e405e2d8d26075480e0d6fe8f", gas:900000, value: 1})
```

the debug console reveals that the second argument `hash` is `null`.

```
5: function Deposit (uint256 timeout, bytes32 hash, address recipient)
6:     public payable returns (uint256)
                                ^^^^^^^ 

debug(testnet1:0x2b899125...)> v

      lock_id: undefined
      timeout: 1521568000
         hash: null
    recipient: '0x0e0060f625534293d280547bd8a782da45333b95'
             : 117
  MAX_TIMEOUT: 0
      m_locks: null
        m_ctr: 0
```

Considering that there is [no such thing as null in Solidity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38036542/2528868), I am confused at the reported value of the `hash` argument. More importantly, passing a value for this parameter has resulted in it being reported back as null by `truffle debug`.

It has received the first argument `timeout` and third argument `recipient` correctly as expected so the call itself seems to be well-formed.

Another variable also seems to be reported back as `null` whilst another is `undefined`. What are the differences between them and why have they been assigned different 'values'?

Why is my `hash` argument being interpreted as `null` when being passed appropriate values?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue; variables that are not null and are in use appear null.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I abandoned the problem... If you ever find anything, please do let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this was a bug before which is fixed now.

Current version i'm using is:

```
$ truffle version
Truffle v5.0.20 (core: 5.0.20)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.15.3
Web3.js v1.0.0-beta.37
```

1. Simple smart contract to reproduce the issue

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.6;

contract TruffleDebug {

  function Deposit (uint256 timeout, bytes32 hash, address recipient) public payable returns (uint256)  {
       emit AcceptCommitted(timeout, hash, recipient);
       return 1;
   }

   event AcceptCommitted(uint256 indexed timeout, bytes32 indexed hash, address indexed recipient);

}
```

2. Run the transaction

```
Deposit(1521568000, '0xffcec51439a3a7195c8f5c32732bfc2bf66688a13c1d52fc9d5e548f4733b5c1,', "0x0e0060f625534293d280547bd8a782da45333b95", {from: "0x00cB2D7146Cc41BeACf4f1Ce42F99619A671708E", gas:900000, value: 1})

tx hash: 0x81076d6629f37dd9d3a0e06617968151e68161c48582a4c83273fc15c436c69b
```

3. Debug the transaction with Truffle

```
$ truffle debug 0x81076d6629f37dd9d3a0e06617968151e68161c48582a4c83273fc15c436c69b
Starting Truffle Debugger...
✔ Compiling your contracts...
✔ Gathering information about your project and the transaction...

(...)

6:   function Deposit (uint256 timeout, bytes32 hash, address recipient) public payable returns (uint256)  {
                                                                                                 ^^^^^^^    

debug(development:0x81076d66...)> v

    timeout: 1521568000
       hash: '0xffcec51439a3a7195c8f5c32732bfc2bf66688a13c1d52fc9d5e548f4733b5c1'
  recipient: '0x0e0060f625534293d280547bd8A782DA45333b95'
        msg: { data:
                '0x03de16ab000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005ab14900ffcec51439a3a7195c8f5c32732bfc2bf66688a13c1d52fc9d5e548f4733b5c10000000000000000000000000e0060f625534293d280547bd8a782da45333b95',
               sig: '0x03de16ab',
               sender:
                '0x00cB2D7146Cc41BeACf4f1Ce42F99619A671708E',
               value: 1 }
         tx: { origin:
                '0x00cB2D7146Cc41BeACf4f1Ce42F99619A671708E',
               gasprice: 20000000000 }
      block: { coinbase:
                '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
               difficulty: 0,
               gaslimit: 6721975,
               number: 41,
               timestamp: 1560166415 }
       this: 'TruffleDebug(0xae5986Fe6A1639e44A1Dd835A1B42c39D0343f42)'
        now: 1560166415

debug(development:0x81076d66...)>
```

As expected, Truffle debug correctly finds the function arguments.